# Upload File and textbox text in same form

Tags: java, html, ajax, servlets

Is it possible to upload a file, and a text input in the same form (i.e., a single submit button click triggers both to be submitted).

```
<form action="DAOserv" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
                        <textarea name="textInput" placeholder="text"
                            class="form-control" rows="11"></textarea>
                        <label for="LInputFile">SQL File</label> <input type="file"
                            id="SQLInputFile">
                    </div>

                <button name="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

In other words, is this snippet of code feasible?

If yes, how would I go about getting the text from the file into a string using AJAX and Java Servlets?

Comment: Your form looks good. You have to place `enctype="multipart/form-data"` Attribute in the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the content of a file via Javascript.  Consequently, you can't send the file contents with AJAX.